# How does ActiveRecord detect last method call in chain?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, method-chaining

Let me visualize that for you.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Product.first.title
#=> "My sample product"
```

Nothing extraordinary here. Just a simple method call. Now take a look at the following example.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def method_missing
  end
end

Product.first.title
#=> nil

Product.first
Product.first.title
#=> "My sample product"
```

How is this possible? In some way they determine the end of the method chain and act upon that? At least thats my theory.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're seeing an artifact of using `irb` to investigate things.

When you say this:

```
> Product.first.title
#=> nil
```

Your `method_missing` will be called to lazy-load the `title` method and you get `nil`.

When you say this:

```
> Product.first
```

You're effectively doing this:

```
> p = Product.first; puts p.inspect
```

The first Product instance will be loaded and then `irb` will call `inspect` on it and AR will add the accessor methods along the way. The result is that Product will now have a `title` method. Hence, doing this:

```
> Product.first
> Product.first.title
```

won't call your `method_missing` at all as there will be a real `title` method for `Product.first.title` to call.

If you try again like this:

```
> Product.first; nil
> Product.first.title
```

You'll see two `nil`s.

---

As far as chaining goes, ActiveRecord doesn't really detect the end, it is just that some method calls naturally require real data from the database and some don't.

If you call `where`, `order`, or any of the other querying methods, you get an [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) instance back and you can chain more query methods and scopes on that relation object. For example, [`where`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c8b584f57625d6b2459c70b6746ab3729f2fde8f/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L132) (which ActiveRecord::Relation gets by including [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html)) looks like this:

```
def where(opts, *rest)
  return self if opts.blank?

  relation = clone
  relation.where_values += build_where(opts, rest)
  relation
end
```

so it just makes a copy of the current query, adds a few things to the copy, and gives you the copy back.

If you call `first`, `last`, `to_a`, `all`, any of the [Enumerable](https://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) methods (i.e. you call `each`), ... then you're asking about specific instances and ActiveRecord will have to execute the query to realize the model instance(s) in question. For example, [`ActiveRecord::Relation#to_a`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d22592a05b299c21e30ec8b38890a178dca863b4/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L149) looks like this:

```
def to_a
  logging_query_plan do
    exec_queries
  end
end
```

and [`all`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d22592a05b299c21e30ec8b38890a178dca863b4/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L158) is little more than a wrapper around `to_a`.

ActiveRecord doesn't really know where the end of the chain is, it just doesn't load anything from the database until it has to so you tell it where the chain ends by saying *go forth and retrieve me some data*.

Comment: i think that it does detect the end of the chain: it's where you don't get back a finder proxy object!

Comment: This isn't what the question is about. The question is why ```Product.first.title``` returns ```nil``` until ```Product.first``` is called, when ```method_missing``` is used inside a model. Once you have called ```Product.first``` title returns ```My sample blog```.

Comment: @user544941: Ah, I see what he asking about: what is replacing or bypassing his `method_missing`.

Comment: @user544941: Do I have the right question now? I think he's just getting confused by things that `irb` is doing behind his back. Thanks for pointing out the confusion BTW.